# Xamarin.iOS - Deep link doesn't work when app is closed

Tags: xamarin.ios, deep-linking

I don't get it, the deeplink is working fine when the app is in background but when it's closed, the app just launch and nothing happens..
Also, since the app is closed at first, I can't debug it (at least I don't know how to do it).

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Best,

Max

Comment: Are you using Url Scheme or third party library to implement deep link? `OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)` will always fire no matter the app is in background or terminated state. You can handle this event to do your configuration.

Comment: I am using the OpenUrl you just gave.. The thing is, since I cannot debug, I ain't sure why it doesn't seems to work..

Comment: You're sure it works on your side when the app is closed? (doesn't even run in background)

Comment: Yes. You can try to show an alert or store a string using NSUserDefaults to confirm whether this event being called. Also try to share your code in this event, it helps us know what effect you want to achieve.

Comment: It's hard to share the code because the app is already complex and because of the confidentiality... I know it makes it complicated.. Do you have any idea about when does OpenUrl would be called? Like before or after `FinishedLaunching`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found out after a while !

Actually, the fact that OpenUrl doesn't get called when the app isn't launched yet is pretty logic.

**Example:** `my_app://query?id=azerty`

- App already in background #launched

  - The `OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)` will get called and in `url` you can find with which link the app has been launched with.
- App not running in background #not_launched

  - The `FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)` will actually have the *url* parameter in the launchOptions. The key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` is then the one you're looking for.

Code sample:

```
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        /* ... */

        if (launchOptions != null && launchOptions.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var url = launchOptions["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey"] as NSUrl;
                var result = AppDeepLinksEntry(url);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { /* ... */ }
        }

        /* ... */
    }

    #region OpenUrl

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        return AppDeepLinksEntry(url);
    }

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
    {
        return AppDeepLinksEntry(url);
    }

    #endregion OpenUrl

    private bool AppDeepLinksEntry(NSUrl url)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"OpenUrl Url : {url}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"OpenUrl Url Query: {url.Query}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"OpenUrl Url Host: {url.Host}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"OpenUrl Url Path: {url.Path}");

        return true;
    }
}
```

I hope the explanation and the code sample above helps you to understand and/or solve your future problems !

Max

Comment: I don't fully agree with that. We could get the url from `launchOptions`, since when app is terminated the event `FinishedLaunching` will be called if we open the app. But as I said above the `OpenUrl()` will always be fired, from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?preferredLanguage=occ) we could know that If a URL arrives while your app is suspended or running in the background, the system moves your app to the foreground prior to calling this method.

Comment: Maybe you're right but I did followed what you said and.. It seems like I don't pass through `OpenUrl` when the app is closed. Also, I tried to just edit the value of a debug var inside AppDelegate and still, nothing.. Maybe it's just our app that create this behavior?